# How to setup multiple websites with Django nginx and uwsgi?

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm really having a tough time getting this to work properly

In my sites enabled folder I have the following two .conf files setup

Site A (this site I setup first and works properly):

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }

# configuration of the server
server {

    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name databank.eaventures.co www.databank.eaventures.co ; # substitute your mac$
    charset     utf-8;
    access_log /srv/www/*****/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/*****/logs/error.log;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /srv/www/******/projectdatabank/media;  # your Django project's m$
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/www/******/projectdatabank/static; # your Django project's s$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
    }
```

Site B (the new site I am trying to add but not getting to work):

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8002; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
    }

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen  80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 50.116.47.120 ***.eaventures.co ; # substitute your machine's IP add$
    charset     utf-8;
    access_log /srv/www/***.capital.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /srv/www/***capital.com/logs/error.log;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /srv/www/***capital.com/***/media;  # your Django project's media$
    }

    location /static {
        alias /srv/www/***capital.com/***/static; # your Django project's stati$
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
        }
    }
```

to start uwsgi I ran the following command (in actuality I run an emperor command however I'd like to tackle one issue at a time here), when I run this site A works completely fine

```
uwsgi --socket :8001 --chdir /srv/www/.com/projectdatabank/ --wsgi-file /srv/www/.com/projectdatabank/databank/wsgi.py
```

Now I run this to try and start site B

```
uwsgi --socket :8002 --chdir /srv/www/***capital.com/***/ --wsgi-file /srv/www/***capital.com/***/***/wsgi.py
```

When I go to the ip address (set on site B) it runs the site django app but does not pull in the css files

any thoughts??

Comment: Sorry guys not sure why this got down voted...let me know how to make this question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working, the problem was the uwsgi_pass

Instead of passing the django variable which I believe is connected to the upstream, i changed it to the following for each file respectively

```
uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8001;
uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8002;
```

Comment: Or you could set `uwsgi_pass` to the `upstream` component. For example, there are 2 `upstream` components in your confs: `django` and `django2`. So, setting `uwsgi_pass` to `django` and `django2` respectively would also work.